# Using rvest to scrape a table after a specific HTML Heading

Tags: r, rvest

I am looking to build an API Scraper, and want to scrape a specific table within each webpage's API.

In this case, I'm looking to scrape the tables after the H4 "Parameters".  See below.

```r
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
library(magrittr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(purrr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

page <- read_html("http://developer.cbssports.com/documentation/api/files/league-stats") 

# List of Tables in Page.  The tables I want are 3:6
page %>% 
  html_table() 
#> [[1]]
#>   X1 X2      X3
#> 1 NA NA Sign-In
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>                                               X1
#> 1                                   League Stats
#> 2                                       Resource
#> 3                                   League Stats
#> 4                                     Change Log
#> 5                               January 15, 2013
#> 6                              February 26, 2015
#> 7                                   HTTP Methods
#> 8                                            GET
#> 9                                     Exceptions
#> 10 Following list of exceptions will be returned
#> 11                                       Example
#> 12                         Retrieve League Stats
#> 13                         XML field definitions
#> 14                                 /league_stats
#> 15                         /league_stats/players
#> 16                  /league_stats/players/player
#> 17              /league_stats/players/player/@id
#> 18             /league_stats/players/player/stat
#>                                                                                                                                   X2
#> 1                                                                                                                                   
#> 2                                                                                                                                   
#> 3            Provides the statistics for a fantasy league by timeframe, period, player status, team id, team totals, and stats type.
#> 4                                                                                                                                   
#> 5                                                                                                                                   
#> 6                                                                                                                                   
#> 7                                                                                                                                   
#> 8  Retrieve stats for a league for a specified timeframe, period, team id, team totals, pro or fantasy, actual stats or projections.
#> 9                                                                                                                                   
#> 10                                                                                                                                  
#> 11                                                                                                                                  
#> 12                                                                                                                                  
#> 13                                                                                                                                  
#> 14                                                                                         A container element for the league stats.
#> 15                                                             A container element for the list of players whose stats are returned.
#> 16                                                                                              A containter element for the player.
#> 17                                                                                                                   ID of a player.
#> 18                                                                               Definition: /league_stats/players/player/stat/@abbr
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>                X1
#> 1 response_format
#> 2           limit
#> 3          offset
#> 4       player_id
#> 5   player_status
#> 6        position
#> 7       timeframe
#> 8          period
#>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        X2
#> 1                                                                                                                (optional) Specifies the format in which the requested resource should be returned.  Valid values are XML and JSON.  The default is XML.
#> 2                                                                                                                                                    (optional) Specifies the number of players to be returned.  By default, the API returns all players.
#> 3                                                                                                                                                                     (optional, defaults to 0) Specifies the offset for the first player to be returned.
#> 4                      (optional, multiple allowed and can be passed as a comma-delimited list, can not be used with player_status, position, team_id, team_type, pro_or_fantasy params) Limit the result set to players with ids specified in this param
#> 5                                                                                                                                                      (optional, defaults to free_agents) Limit the result set by player_status (‘free_agents’ or ‘all’)
#> 6 (optional, defaults to all batters, multiple allowed and can be passed as a comma-delimited list) Limits the result set to a particular position, which is specified by a position code.  For a list of position codes, request the Positions resource.
#> 7                                                                         (optional, defaults to current year) Year for which stats are being requested (any year in YYYY format from 1997 to current year).  Only supported period for past years is ytd
#> 8                                                                                                                                                                                 (optional, defaults to ytd) Period for which stats are being requested.
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>           X1
#> 1 stats_type
#>                                                                                                                                                                                    X2
#> 1 (optional, defaults to ‘stats’) Determines if the resource will include actual stats, projections or Football Red Zone Stats.  Possible values are (stats, projections or redzone).
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>       X1
#> 1 source
#>                                                                                                               X2
#> 1 (optional, defaults to ‘cbs’ for stats_type=projections) The source for which projections are being requested.
#> 
#> [[6]]
#>               X1
#> 1        team_id
#> 2      team_type
#> 3 pro_or_fantasy
#>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      X2
#> 1                                                                                                                                                          (required if requesting stats for a particular team or team totals) ID of the fantasy team whose stats are being requested (use all to get team totals).  To get a list of fantasy team codes, request the <Teams> resource.
#> 2                                                                                                                                                                                                        (optional, defaults to ‘roster’) Determine whether to get a team’s roster or their scout team (‘roster’, ‘active’, ‘reserve’ or ‘scout_team’).  Can only be used with team_id.
#> 3 (optional, defaults to ‘fantasy’) Determines whether to count the stats for players only when they were active on the fantasy team’s roster or even when they were on the bench (‘fantasy’ or ‘pro’).  Can only be used with team_id.  fantasy is only supported for current year and periods ytd, y, period_number, or Xd (Last X Days), team_type active, and for stats_type stats.

# List of H4 in Page
page %>% 
  html_nodes("h4") # I want the 3rd value "Parameters"
#> {xml_nodeset (13)}
#>  [1] <h4 class="CHeading">Description</h4>\n
#>  [2] <h4 class="CHeading">URL</h4>\n
#>  [3] <h4 class="CHeading">Parameters</h4>\n
#>  [4] <h4 class="CHeading">Sample URL</h4>\n
#>  [5] <h4 class="CHeading">XML Response</h4>\n
#>  [6] <h4 class="CHeading">Notes</h4>\n
#>  [7] <h4 class="CHeading">JSON Response</h4>\n
#>  [8] <h4 class="CHeading">Notes</h4>\n
#>  [9] <h4 class="CHeading">Sample URL</h4>\n
#> [10] <h4 class="CHeading">XML Response</h4>\n
#> [11] <h4 class="CHeading">Notes</h4>\n
#> [12] <h4 class="CHeading">JSON Response</h4>\n
#> [13] <h4 class="CHeading">Notes</h4>\n


# Manual way to get information I'm looking for
parameters <- page %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  .[3:6] %>% 
  dplyr::bind_rows()
```

How do I go about only getting the tables that come after Parameters?  Is there a more direct way to do this without having to look at the tables reference each time?

Comment: 3:6 are before HTTP Methods section which is where params table is located

Comment: I meant [[3]]:[[6]]

Answer (score 0):

How about better specifying the ending note through `html_nodes()`?

```r
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
library(magrittr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(purrr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

page <- read_html("http://developer.cbssports.com/documentation/api/files/league-stats") 

page %>% 
  html_nodes("h4")
#> {xml_nodeset (13)}
#>  [1] <h4 class="CHeading">Description</h4>\n
#>  [2] <h4 class="CHeading">URL</h4>\n
#>  [3] <h4 class="CHeading">Parameters</h4>\n
#>  [4] <h4 class="CHeading">Sample URL</h4>\n
#>  [5] <h4 class="CHeading">XML Response</h4>\n
#>  [6] <h4 class="CHeading">Notes</h4>\n
#>  [7] <h4 class="CHeading">JSON Response</h4>\n
#>  [8] <h4 class="CHeading">Notes</h4>\n
#>  [9] <h4 class="CHeading">Sample URL</h4>\n
#> [10] <h4 class="CHeading">XML Response</h4>\n
#> [11] <h4 class="CHeading">Notes</h4>\n
#> [12] <h4 class="CHeading">JSON Response</h4>\n
#> [13] <h4 class="CHeading">Notes</h4>\n

# List of Tables in Page.  The tables I want are 3:6
out = page %>% 
  html_nodes("#Content > div.CHTTPMethods > div > div > table:nth-child(5)") %>% 
  html_table()

table_1 = out[[1]]
out = page %>% 
  html_nodes("#Content > div.CHTTPMethods > div > div > table:nth-child(18)") %>% 
  html_table()
table_2 = out[[1]]

table_1
#>                X1
#> 1 response_format
#> 2           limit
#> 3          offset
#> 4       player_id
#> 5   player_status
#> 6        position
#> 7       timeframe
#> 8          period
#>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        X2
#> 1                                                                                                                (optional) Specifies the format in which the requested resource should be returned.  Valid values are XML and JSON.  The default is XML.
#> 2                                                                                                                                                    (optional) Specifies the number of players to be returned.  By default, the API returns all players.
#> 3                                                                                                                                                                     (optional, defaults to 0) Specifies the offset for the first player to be returned.
#> 4                      (optional, multiple allowed and can be passed as a comma-delimited list, can not be used with player_status, position, team_id, team_type, pro_or_fantasy params) Limit the result set to players with ids specified in this param
#> 5                                                                                                                                                      (optional, defaults to free_agents) Limit the result set by player_status (‘free_agents’ or ‘all’)
#> 6 (optional, defaults to all batters, multiple allowed and can be passed as a comma-delimited list) Limits the result set to a particular position, which is specified by a position code.  For a list of position codes, request the Positions resource.
#> 7                                                                         (optional, defaults to current year) Year for which stats are being requested (any year in YYYY format from 1997 to current year).  Only supported period for past years is ytd
#> 8                                                                                                                                                                                 (optional, defaults to ytd) Period for which stats are being requested.
table_2
#>               X1
#> 1        team_id
#> 2      team_type
#> 3 pro_or_fantasy
#>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      X2
#> 1                                                                                                                                                          (required if requesting stats for a particular team or team totals) ID of the fantasy team whose stats are being requested (use all to get team totals).  To get a list of fantasy team codes, request the <Teams> resource.
#> 2                                                                                                                                                                                                        (optional, defaults to ‘roster’) Determine whether to get a team’s roster or their scout team (‘roster’, ‘active’, ‘reserve’ or ‘scout_team’).  Can only be used with team_id.
#> 3 (optional, defaults to ‘fantasy’) Determines whether to count the stats for players only when they were active on the fantasy team’s roster or even when they were on the bench (‘fantasy’ or ‘pro’).  Can only be used with team_id.  fantasy is only supported for current year and periods ytd, y, period_number, or Xd (Last X Days), team_type active, and for stats_type stats.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I like the use of "Parameters" and not nodes since the nodes might be different on different pages of the API.

Comment: I get that. Then there must be a manual page where you get to understand how the "Parameters" really work. This is the fastest way of getting your tables out.

Comment: What do you mean by manual page?  I thought the page I was referring to was a manual page.